# NodeJs request response body is empty

Tags: node.js, express, requestjs

Don't understand why the response body of the following request is empty:

**request:**

```
req.headers['User-Agent'] = 'request';
req.headers['Accept'] = 'text/html';

const options = {
    url: config.prodURL,
    headers: req.headers,
    qs: req.query,
    method: req.method
};
request(options, (err, resp, body) => {

       console.log(resp);
});
```

I'm expecting HTML in this response, but for some reason, when I look at `resp` it displays  `body: ''`

Part of the `resp` contains the `href` url and if I use this in any client, it displays the  HTML code.

What is wrong with this config?

### update

Here's the data with the exception of `href`as I cannot share this URL. `err is null`, here are the rest of the values:

```
{ url: 'http://my.url/',
  headers:
   { 'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.15.2',
     accept: '*/*',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'postman-token': '8c208831-580b-4460-b3e0-046d85789658',
     host: 'localhost:8001',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'User-Agent': 'request',
     Accept: 'text/html' },
  qs: { query-params... },
  method: 'GET' 
}
```

I believe it might be related to the response headers, the URL requested doesn't return any, so does `requestJs` require a `content-type` to be able to parse the body?

Comment: Did you check `err` to see if there's an error?  Then, please add the actual URL to your question so we can try it ourselves?  What are the values of `config.prodURL`, `req.headers`, `req.query` and `req.method`?

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, `err` is null, I can't share `href`, just rest assured that it responds html. The rest is updated in the question

Comment: Well, "rest assured" that if you duplicated that same parameters in your `request()` call that your other clients so, then you'd see the desired output.  Since you're not willing to show us that or allow us to reproduce anything, you've posted a question that all people can do is make wild guesses about.   We can't debug or problem solve anything ourselves.  These types of questions often never get answers because of the lack of specific information to reproduce the problem.